# How to know in codebehind when XmlDataProvider has filled target controll with data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xmldataprovider

The title of my question says it already.
How can I check if my XmlDataProvider has filled my DataGrid in code behind.
It already works, but I want to check when it is finished so I can style the cells in my DataGrid(ForeGround, Background, TextWeight) before the user is able to do/see anything:

```
public ExcelWindow(string filePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _filePath = filePath;

    Dispatcher.beginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        LoadScreenSettings();
    }));

    LoadXml();

    CellLayoutHandler = new CellLayoutHandler(DataGridXml, _FilePath);
}

private void LoadXml()
{
    XmlDataProvider dataProvider = xmlDataProvider;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(_FilePath);
    dataProvider.Document = xmlDoc;
    dataProvider.XPath = "Data/Row";
}
```

Comment: 1) If you want to see exactly see when it is finished, alternatively you can use Background worker. Backgroundworker has event like "RunWorkerCompleted"

Comment: 2) Or just create a custom data grid style regarding your data in XML.

Comment: Ok I will look into it thanks! But there has to be an easier way to do this right? I can't imagine it is that hard to achieve this in a simpler way..

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `LoadingRow` event : `Dgrd.LoadingRow += DgrdParent_LoadingRow;`, beauty of this event is only visible Rows fire this event, if you scroll down or increase the size of the `Window`, remaining relevant rows will fire this event.
2. Use `HasItems` property. This property becomes `True` only when `DataGrid` is finished with its `ItemsSource`.